# Error API Android?

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buen día comunidad, saludos cordiales. Tengo un problema con una app, tiene un login, que al momento ingresar, cuando uso Android 7.0 o superior funciona con normalidad, y si hago lo mismo en un dispositivo con Android menor a 7 se cierra y me arroja estos errores (imagenes), estoy dedicando mi API mínima 21, dedicada 26 y máxima 26, pero si cambio las versiones de las Apis me sale el mismo error

Comment: el problema viene de que no esta encontrando algun tipo de recurso para correr , el problema esta en el NavigationMenu, tenes algo del codigo que usaste o donde te sale el error ?

Comment: Bienvenido. Fran...., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, tu código, más información, etc, saludos!